# Extrapolating rarefaction curves

Tags: biostatistics, community-ecology, microbiome, species-distribution, gut-bacteria

I am interested in methods for extrapolating rarefaction curves and/or estimating the true species richness. The ecosystem of interest is the gut microbiome and extrapolation is to higher sequencing.

**Chao estimator**
The ubiquitous approach is the one based on Chao estimator (see Eqs. [7] and [17-19] in [this review](http://chao.stat.nthu.edu.tw/wordpress/paper/97.pdf)). However [this approach has been recently criticized](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23407313/), since it assumes that the undetected species have the same abundance as the rarest detected species - therefore, at best, it gives only the lower bound for the diversity.

**Hill numbers**
I am not convinced that using other diversity metrics (most fo which can be represented via [Hill numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index)) solves the problem. Indeed, most of these metrics have better statistical properties than richness (=number of species), since they give more weight to observe species over the unobserved ones - essentially, they hide the problem under the carpet.

**Alternative 1: Using Relative abundance distributions**
Making an assumption about actual [species abundance distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_species_abundance) (e.g., assuming it to be log-normal or Fisher log-series - whatever is applicable) seems promising. However I have not found any solid publication describing such an approach.

**Alternative 2: Comparing rarefaction curves**
Alternative approach, employed in package [MOMR](https://github.com/eprifti/momr), is using the rarefaction curves for many samples to extend the other rarefaction cruves.

**Question**
I am looking for guidance (preferably references with sufficient mathematical details) regarding the two approaches listed above, as well as for possible other alternatives.

Comment: Quick question: Are you interested in developing a novel method of estimating true richness, evaluating different methods, or are you simply analyzing your own data and trying to find the best estimates to report? For a community like the gut microbiota, the methods used in sample collection, storage, DNA extraction, sequencing technology, and sequence assembly/curation etc., will probably impact the richness estimates more than the specific diversity metrics used in the final analysis.

Comment: @MikeyC I am interested in evaluating different methods. Ultimately, these estimates will serve as a biomarker (one of several) for specific health conditions, so it will be used with extensive amounts of data. For a moment I see that the estimates vary rather wildely... (even though I agree with your assertion that there are plenty of other sources of errors).